# How to have jobs running in background in R

Tags: r, subprocess

While doing interactive analyses in R I sometimes find myself stopped
by some task that needs a long time to run, but whose results I do not immediately to keep working.

What are some possible approaches to run the long commands in background, while being able to access the other objects I have in my workspace for my analyses?

Comment: Are you working in R or R studio?

Comment: mainly R studio

Answer (score 0):

R does not support background processes per se.  The usual approach is to launch a second instance of R via `R CMD batch` and make the results available in a stored file.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the different processes on different r sessions and run those sessions writing the results or objects to a file/db when they are finished. Then you could have a main session which periodically checks if the objects have been written so that they can be read when the other processes have finished. Not ideal and even a little messy but could work depending on what you're trying to achieve.